# MATLAB: Why is symbolic substitution so slow and what are the faster alternatives?

Tags: matlab

On my machine, the following code:

```
for i=1:200
    1+2+5;
end;
```

runs in 0.000180 seconds.

Now, this code:

```
syms x y z
f(x,y,z) = x + y+z;

for i=1:200
    f(1,2,5);
end;
```

is much slower (6.193909 seconds).

For my code, I need to write the derivatives of several complicated functions of 3 variables, and then plug in all the integer points in a given domain. It would help A LOT to be able to do symbolic differentiation and then plugging in, but this seems amazingly slow.

Is there any alternative other than doing everything manually (writing the full derivatives by hand)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to speed up the calculation:

```
syms x y z
f(x,y,z) = x + y+z;
h= matlabFunction(f);
for i=1:200
    h(1,2,5);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. Still slower than the other one, but much better.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a fair comparison since in the first one you are using small integers and no function call.

```
tic,for i = 1:200 f(1,2,5); end;toc % 1.355852 on average

g = @(x,y,z) x + y + z;
tic,for i = 1:200 g(1,2,5); end;toc % 0.000231 on average

syms x y z real
f(x,y,z) = x + y+z;
h = matlabFunction(f);
tic,for i = 1:200 g(1,2,5); end;toc % 0.000233 on average
```

Regardless. you should evaluate the derivatives numerically not symbolically with varying degrees of complexity depending on your application.